# Check if major mode is equal one of several emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I found a snippet to close all dired buffers, which I want to use in sunrise commander:

```
(defun er/kill-all-dired-buffers()
      "Kill all dired buffers."
      (interactive)
      (save-excursion
        (let((count 0))
          (dolist(buffer (buffer-list))
            (set-buffer buffer)
            (when (equal major-mode 'sr-mode) 
              (or (equal major-mode 'dired-mode))
              (setq count (1+ count))
              (kill-buffer buffer)))
          (message "Killed %i dired buffer(s)." count ))))
(setq sr-quit-hook 'er/kill-all-dired-buffers)
```

Issue being, I can't make it work both for sr-mode and dired-mode together.
How do I check "if major mode is sr-mode OR dired-mode"?

---

EDIT:
Just a syntax error.
Should be

```
(when (or (equal major-mode 'dired-mode) (equal major-mode 'sr-mode))
```

Have to admit it's not too intuitive.

Comment: yep yep, that's what I was missing.

Comment: It's perfectly intuitive.  Your original code is like writing `if (foo) { || bar; baz(); }` in C.

Comment: That's not intuitive either. Not convinced. Intuitive would be if (foo || bar) { baz(); }.

Comment: Well prefix operators are completely intuitive in a language which consistently uses prefix operators :) Stefan has provided the best solution, but also note that if you weren't interested in any potential derived modes then you could use `(when (memq major-mode '(sr-mode dired-mode)) ...)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The canonical way would be `(when (derived-mode-p 'sr-mode 'dired-mode) ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried some things and found this to work on my emacs-ielm - perhaps it might help also:

```
(if (member major-mode '(fsharp-mode c-mode java-mode inferior-emacs-lisp-mode))
(message "yeah right"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the correct check function is:

```
(derived-mode-p &rest MODES)
```

See 'subr.el'.

Comment: You've duplicated the accepted answer (about 5 years later). I suggest deleting this.